# Open Smart-TV Browser from within App

Tags: javascript, browser, samsung-smart-tv

We are in the process of developing an app for Samsungs Smart TV.

Is there a way to open a webpage in the browser from within our app?

Basically I am looking for something akin to Androids intent-mechanism. Setting `location.href = "http://www.foo.com"` replaces my Apps DOM with the new page, which is not what I want. Looking through Samsungs API documentation I could not find anything related.

I also tried `window.open`.

*edit*: I found a [thread](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/a56519250d733296?forumID=28382a653626599f) in the samsung developer forum linking to an [oddly named method](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/common_module_widget_object.html#ref00006-common-module-widget-object-runsearchwidget) in the WidgetAPI. Someone in the thread says

> So to launch WebBrowser, you need appID for that app.

Which I do not have.

*edit2* this code opens a browser, but only the default page, not the passed one. I am still missing any documentation on how to pass a specific address.

```
new Common.API.Widget().runSearchWidget('29_fullbrowser','http://www.google.com');
```

Comment: I don't have even the smallest clue, but I pressume you already tried stuff like `window.open` right?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I already tried that, no success.

Comment: Have you tried creating an `<iframe>` and loading the document in there?

Comment: I did not try that, but for the moment we would like to open the webpage in the systems browser, if possible.

Comment: @msung Assumed it wouldn't work, but sometimes the easiest things are overlooked. My guess is that Pekka will be right and that your only option will turn out to be using an iframe, but my experience and knowledge about SSTV is quite limited.

Comment: @Sarah: If you're still looking for a solution, feel free to check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an undocumented member of `Common.API.Widget` instances called `runWebBrowser()`.  I'm unsure how long it's been there, but the definition looks like this:

```
this.runWebBrowser = function(pURL, pKeyWord) {
    var type = Common.API.EVENT_ENUM.RUN_WEBBROWSER ;
    var data = curWidget.id + "|?|" + pURL + "|?|" + pKeyWord;
    var widgetEvent = new WidgetEvent(type, data);  // async call
    sendWidgetEvent("", widgetEvent, false);
}
```

I've tested this on my 2013 Samsung Smart TV, and it works.  The browser even gracefully restarts your app if the <kbd>Return</kbd> key on the remote is pressed.

Comment: Sounds great. Since I no longer have access to a Samsung TV I can't verify.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have found no solution yet and nobody seems to have one I'll answer my own question:

As of April 2013 this is not possible.

Comment: msung, can I use your post to ask something? The browsers on Samsung Smart-TV looks like what? Chrome? My web-site need to run on the new tv's. Do you have any tip/advice about it?